# R create vector with proportions

Tags: r, vector, percentage

I am attempting to create a ventor of N length with five possible choices (0,1,2,3,4 with replacement).  However, I would like 30% of N numbers be 0. I am having trouble coming up with a simple statement to achieve this, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything is right there in `?sample`. Try `sample(0:4,N,replace=TRUE,c(.3,.175,.175,.175,.175))`

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the OP is that *exactly* 30% of the `N` values should be zero. If that is correct, then this approach works:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- sample(1:4, n, TRUE, rep(.25, 4))
x[sample(1:100, 0.3 * n, FALSE)] <- 0
table(x)

x
 0  1  2  3  4 
30 17 15 25 13
```